# How to install protobuf-net on Visual Studio 2012 using NuGet?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, protocol-buffers

I would like to install protobuf-net using NutGet and Visual Studio 2012.

However, if I try to install it, I got the following error message from NuGet :

> 'protobuf-net' already has a dependency defined for
>   'NETStandard.Library'.

I have tried to install NETStandard.Library but there is an error :

> The 'NETStandard.Library 1.6.0' package requires NuGet client version
>   '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60318.667'.

I also tried to update NuGet (by uninstalling it then re-install), but it seems with Visual Studio 2012 it is stuck to 2.8 version.

Comment: Does it work if you try to install the previous version of protobuf? From package manager console: `Install-Package protobuf-net -Version 2.0.0.668`

Comment: It worked beautifully. Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have Visual Studio 2012 to test, but I wonder if this is due to the way Nuget now works with the .Net Core dependencies. It should work if you install an older version of [protobuf-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/). You can see that the [older version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/2.0.0.668) doesn't mention .NETStandard as a dependency. To do this, from the package manager console, type this:

```
Install-Package protobuf-net -Version 2.0.0.668
```

Comment: I'm using VS2013 and have the same error... it sucks not being able to install latest version of the package

Answer (score 1):

I found that this **protobuf-portable-net** works on .NET 4.5 for VS 2013 and has the same version number as above: `2.0.0.668`. It's the same author and might be a better approach than intentionally installing an old version of a newer package. 
[image]